# Python subprocess: How do I highlight a file in Windows Exlorer based on a variable?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, explorer

From Python 3.9 I want to highlight a file in Windows Explorer based on a variable.
The below code works fine for a fixed file, e.g.: *Y:\picturefile.1234567890.jpg*
How can I replace this fixed file by a variable so I can let it work for any file from a list?

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess


def highlightfile():

    subprocess.run(r'explorer /select,Y:\picturefile.1234567890.jpg')


root = Tk()

# Button to open Windows Explorer and highlight picture file
btn = Button(text="Highlight picture file", command=highlightfile)
btn.pack(side='top')

root.mainloop()
```

When I replace in the code *Y:\picturefile.1234567890.jpg* by for instance the variable *picturename* (containing the same path and file) PyCharm gives an error message: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System cannot find the specified file.
So, the below code does NOT work; why not?

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess


def highlightfile():
    picturename = "Y:\\picturefile.1234567890.jpg"
    subprocess.run(r'explorer /select, picturename')


root = Tk()

# Button to open Windows Explorer and highlight picture file
btn = Button(text="Highlight picture file", command=highlightfile)
btn.pack(side='top')

root.mainloop()
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the question myself.
As I have been searching for a long time I show my solution below to help others.

Instead of just replacing the filename I replaced the whole argument of subprocess.run():

```
def highlightfile():
    run_arg = r'explorer /select, "' + picturename + '"'
    subprocess.run(run_arg)
```

This works as intended.

Comment: This is a good thing to do, you can even accept your own answer (although you won't receive any reputation for doing so).

Comment: This should work the same without separate variable. Could you add the _broken_ code to your question?